# How to copy field in PivotTable

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I want to copy a field in the PivotTable summary area. Below is my PivotTable:

```
Group_Age Sum of attrition_flag Count of acct_id Max of age
1            73            661             27
2            65            663             37
3            54            779             57
4            32            467             59
5            40            725             62
```

Now if I also want to add Min of age, how do I do that?

Currently I am trying to copy and paste field "Max of age" in the summary area and change the field settings, but I am unable to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Just drag the Age field into Σ VALUES a second time and for this "Summarize value field by" Min.